# Is there a way to create a calculated field using results of another calculated field?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, pivot-table

Is it possible to use the results of a calculated field as part of a new calculated field? I know further calculation could be done outside the pivot table but I was hoping there was a way to somehow do this within the pivot table.

Appreciate your feedback!

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: Sure can ... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10EAvsom1wFT7cfcUHPnH4f0Xu8by82SFiTtOSKN8PPI/edit#gid=1994091835

Comment: On the sheet, I want to take the calculated field "Weekly Budget (Col E) and subtract from it the spreadsheet field "Current Week's Spend (Col D)

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sorry ... newer to the site.   What address should I direct to so you can access it?

Comment: np, in your sheet do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTFcv.png

Answer (score 1):

**Accessing the values of one calculated field in another such field from the Pivot Table menu doesn't seem possible.**

Here are two facts that were encouraging, but I suspect are dead ends:

- Access columns from the origin sheet of your pivot table via their header values;
- There is a GETPIVOTDATA() function to access pivot table data.

Regardless of trying to reference pivot table headers local to the workbook or as absolute values, I wasn't able to make it cooperate.

As another misfortune, you can't create a table which explicitly references another. So while you can create a new column with cells referencing cells, any expansion or contraction of the table may cause those outside cells to become inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this question but I've just crossed with the same problem and the answer is: you just copy the formula used in the previous calculated field in the new one and add the remaining calculations to it.

Imagine you have this as the first calculated field:
Calculated field 1 = **SUM(Column name A) / SUM(Column name B) * COUNTA(Column name C)**

And on the second calculated field you want to achieve this:
Calculated field 2 = **Calculated field 1** * COUNTA (Column name D)

Since you can't do it, it becomes like this:
Calculated field 2  = **SUM(Column name A) / SUM(Column name B)** * COUNTA(Column name C) * COUNTA (Column name D)